# Expression rewriting

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

i have the following expression

```
(w3^2 
   (3 t5 w2^2 w3^2 w4^2 y3^2 + 
     w5^2 (3 t4 w2^2 w3^2 y3^2 + 
       w4^2 (12 t3 w2^2 y3^2 + 3 t2 w3^2 y3^2 - 12 t3^2 w2^2 y3 θ5 + 
               4 t3^3 w2^2 θ5^2)))) /
(4 t3^3 (t5 w2^2 w3^2 w4^2 + (t4 w2^2 w3^2 + (t3 w2^2 + t2 w3^2) w4^2) w5^2))
```

I want to rewrite it to the form

```
θ5^2/A - (3*y3*θ5)/A^2 + (3*y3^2)/A^3
```

where `A` must be properly defined. Is there a way to find a proper `A`?

Comment: you have syntax error in your code `t4 \ w2^2` so I removed that extra \ you have.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
expr = (w3^2*(3*t5*w2^2*w3^2*w4^2*y3^2 + 
      w5^2*(3*t4*w2^2*w3^2*y3^2 + 
         w4^2*(12*t3*w2^2*y3^2 + 3*t2*w3^2*y3^2 - 
            12*t3^2*w2^2*y3*θ5 + 
            4*t3^3*w2^2*θ5^2))))/(4*
    t3^3*(t5*w2^2*w3^2*
       w4^2 + (t4*w2^2*w3^2 + (t3*w2^2 + t2*w3^2)*w4^2)*w5^2));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr2 = θ5^2/A - (3*y3*θ5)/A^2 + (3*y3^2)/A^3;
sol = First@Solve[expr == expr2, A];

expr3 = expr2 /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Simplify@(expr3 - expr)
 (* 0 *)
```